# Problems creating a round UIImageView with Storyboard [Xamarin]

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uikit, uistoryboard

I am facing a weird problem and am sure that I oversee something obvious:
I want to get a round image like this:
[image]

I perform the following action to round the corners of my UIImageView:

```
        testImage.Layer.CornerRadius = testImage.Frame.Size.Height * 0.5f;
        testImage.ClipsToBounds = true;
```

In my storyboard the ImageView has a constraint to left and right of 60, top 92 and an AspectRatio of 1:1.

[image]

However, when I run the app I receive the following on iPhone 6plus:
[image]

I played a bit around with the CornerRadius and could produce the required circle with 100 on iPhone 5, 125 on iPhone 6 and 150 on iPhone 6plus.

When I generate everything from code like this:

```
        var testImage = new UIImageView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 150, 150));
        testImage.Image = UIImage.FromFile ("kitten.jpg");
        testImage.Layer.CornerRadius = testImage.Frame.Size.Height * 0.5f;
        testImage.ClipsToBounds = true;
        View.Add (testImage);
```

I get the expected result:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong with the storyboard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your first instance, you're assuming the height and width are equal because the Aspect Ratio is set to 1:1; in your second instance, you're actually creating a `UIImageView` that's setting the height and width to  equal values. If you set the Priority of the Aspect Ratio constraint to a number higher than the Priority of any other constraint, you should get a circle.

Answer (score 0):

I've double-checked this in Xcode, so I'll put it in as an answer:

In your first instance, you're assuming the height and width are equal because the Aspect Ratio is set to 1:1; in your second instance, you're actually creating a UIImageView that's setting the height and width to equal values. If you set the Priority of the Aspect Ratio constraint to a number higher than the Priority of any other constraint, you should get a circle.

Comment: Hi Glenn, 
just tried that out: When I set all other priorities to e.g. 750 the UIImageView is completely misplaced :/ Have you managed it to keep it in the center of the screen?

Comment: Try using only a top constraint and a left constraint, along with the Aspect Ratio constraint.

Comment: You can't use the same values you had before for the top and left constraints. You have to set the left constraint to (a percentage width of the screen + half the width of the image), the top constraint to (a percentage height of the screen + half the height of the image). I'm guessing the percentage would be somewhere around 20%, but you should try values on either side of that figure. Might even be 15%. Might even be different values for width and height.  Of course, that means dealing with the constraints programmatically rather than through the Storyboard.

Comment: And I don't know why I didn't think of the constraints you can set up to center the object horizontally and vertically!  With any offset you need! And then you don't need any top, bottom, left or right constraints!